# WPF Toolkit doesn't get displayed in the toolbox

Tags: wpf, reference, toolkit

I installed the wpftoolkit.msi and added a reference to it, but it doesn't get dipslayed in the toolbox, is there anything else that needs to be done? I followed the instructions from [the code plex site](http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535), I can access some of the controls from code, only a few, I added WPFToolkit as a reference, does any other reference need to be added for the chart controls and so that they can be accessed from the toolbox?

EDIT: I added all dlls in the folder and still cannot access the chart control.

**Answer:** I provided an answer bellow you neeed to include a different namespace for the charts the default one from the codeplex site doesn't include all controls.

Answer (score 5):

I believe this is the answer if you want to add the charting controls to your toolbox.
If you just add a reference to what the codeplex site says you won't get all controls.

`using Microsoft.Windows.Controls` doesn't work you need to include the reference name, if you click on properties for the reference name you can copy name, for charting it is: `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit`

For the toolbox:

Go to your toolbox, right click create a new tab. In the new tab right click choose items add all the controls from the `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit` namespace. You should have all of them in the toolbox.

Answer (score 2):

Here it is http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/40535

**Installation and Usage Instructions**

Please note: The WPF Toolkit is dependent on .NET Framework 3.5 SP1. You must install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 in order to use any features in the Toolkit.

Instructions for using the WPF Toolkit binaries:

Install .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

If you have a previous version of WPF Toolkit installed, uninstall it through the Remove Programs dialog on the Control Panel (look for "WPF Toolkit October 2008" or "WPF Toolkit January 2009" or "WPF Toolkit March 2009" or "WPF Toolkit June 2009")

Download the WPFToolkit_Binaries or WPFToolkit_BinariesAndSource

Run the WPFToolkit.msi to install the WPFToolkit.dll and WPF Toolkit design time binaries to your Program Files folder

Reference the binaries in your project:

Reference WPFToolkit.dll in your project

Add a using statement ("using Microsoft.Windows.Controls;") to the top of .cs files
Add a new xmlns (for example, xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit") to the top of XAML files
Remember to use the namespace prefix (in the above example, ) in the body of your XAML

Comment: @Dimitry Boyko, thanks i was missing the microsoft include, I updated the  question, I can only access a few of them and still cannot see them in the toolbox.